# ¿Cómo mostrar el valor de una etiqueta usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

mi problema es el siguiente:
Tengo un navbar el cual despliega todas las categorías obtenidas de la BD, dichas categorías las muestro en una etiqueta data id="categoria" value="$c->nombre" para poder acceder a su valor mas adelante.
E usado el evento onclick="traer()" para activar el script que permita apuntar al id="categoria" e imprimir su respectivo valor por consola.

**Vista Inicio**

```
  <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    @foreach($categorias as $c)
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown" onclick="traer()">
                        <data id="categoria" value="{{$c->nombre}}">{{$c->nombre}}</data>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
```

**script traer()**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function traer() {
        var categoriaSel = document.getElementById('categoria').value;
        console.log('categoria seleccionada ' + categoriaSel);
    }
</script>
```

Al momento de chequear en consola, haciendo clic en diferentes categorías, solo me muestra el valor de la primera categoría (Colchones).

[image: Barra de navegación con las categorías cargadas]

[image: Mensajes devueltos por consola]

En conclusión lo que deberia obtener es que al hacer clic sobre Colchones, se muestre por consola la categoria colchones; al hacer clic sobre salas, se muestre por consola la categoria salas y asi con las demas categorias.

A mi parecer debo usar addListener o algo parecido pero no lo tengo muy claro, les agradecería su apoyo en como poder solucionar este problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los [ID deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) y, para cada elemento, estás repitiéndolos; es por eso que siempre obtienes el mismo valor.

Lo más adecuado es obtener el elemento que recibió clic y, a partir de ahí, obtener los valores.

Por último, no es recomendable tener los eventos en la misma etiqueta `onclick=traer()`; es mejor obtener todos los elementos desde Javascript y asignar el evento a cada uno para facilitar el mantenimiento de tus proyectos.

```js
// Crear función para los clics, recibiendo el evento como parámetro
function traer(e) {
    // e.currentTarget es el elemento LI
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
    // Ver el valor de data
    console.log(e.currentTarget.querySelector('data').value);
    // Ver el texto de data
    console.log(e.currentTarget.querySelector('data').textContent);
}

// Ejecutar hasta que se haya cargado el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
    // Obtener todos los li y asignar evento
    document.querySelectorAll('li.nav-item').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', traer);
    });
});
```

```css
data:hover::after {
    content: ' (ID ' attr(value) ')';
    font-size: .7em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <data value="1">Categoría 1</data>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <data value="2">Categoría 2</data>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <data value="3">Categoría 3</data>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <data value="4">Categoría 4</data>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <data value="5">Categoría 5</data>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Adicional:** Probablemente la etiqueta [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/data) no sea necesaria, también se puede "jugar" con [atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: muchas gracias Triby, has solucionado a la perfección mi problema, algún libro o documento que me recomiendes para aprender más sobre javascript y el manejo del DOM ?